# ReactNative in app purchase in multi device

Tags: android, ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, payment

I am developing an application which allows user can buy a product using In app purchase of Apple/Google.

My app has no login function.

User can buy product by Apple ID or Google ID.

https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap

We are using this library.

For example: I have a product -> Product A (**Auto‑Renewable Subscriptions**)

If user buy this product, in my app, it will be displayed as " BOUGHT A "

Device A: using apple id/google id example@example.com buy product A

Then after that Device A will displayed as "BOUGHT A"
Device B: the same apple id/google id example@example.com
I want in device B also "BOUGHT A" because device b also use example@example.com

Can I do it?

I don't want to save apple id or google id in back-end server.

Comment: If device B is the same type of device (iOS/Android) and the purchase type is non-consumable then the purchase will be visible in the receipt on iOS (and whatever the equivalent is for Android).  If they are different device types then no

Comment: thank you. purchase type is Auto‑Renewable Subscriptions. it is OK? and can you talk me about how to device B can get current product?

Comment: On iOS you retrieve the receipt and you will see the in-app purchase in it.

Comment: now, I am using verifyReceipt API to retrieve receipt. but in device B, I don't know receipt data, has another way to retrieve the receipt in device B?